# Raw sockets on NaCl?

Tags: sockets, google-chrome, google-nativeclient, raw-sockets

Right now I'm trying to migrate a code written in C to a application for Chrome browser.

I'm new in programming on the NaCl for Chrome Apps and I don't get really good if with the native client I can use the raw sockets. I need to use the raw sockets because I must create modified packets such as UDP with TTL very low.

So in general my question is, Can I use raw sockets (C style) with the NaCl? If the answer is yes, If you could provide some extra information, It would be great.

Answer (score 2):

You can use TCP and UDP sockets, via the nacl_io library. Look at the nacl_io demo in the Native Client SDK. It can be found in the subdirectory `examples/demo/nacl_io_demo`.

Please note that these sockets APIs are only allowed when running as a Chrome App, not on the open web.